# HQL Login with username and email from two different tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, hql

I have Form with inputs username and password to login my app.

This is my query:

```
public LoginUsr logInUsr(RequestLoginUsr request) {
         List<User> l = getCurrentSession()
         .createQuery("from User where name = :username and pass = :password")
         .setParameter("username", request.getUsername())
         .setParameter("password", request.getPassword())
         .getResultList();

      if(l.size() == 1) {
         User u = l.get(0);
         return new LoginUsr(u.getSurname(),u.getId(),u.getFkUsrPrc(), null);
      } else {
         return null;
      }
   }
```

RequestLoginUsr :

```
public class RequestLoginUsr {
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private Integer moduleId;
   private Integer computerId;
}
```

It's working but...

Now I would add possibility then input `name` was also `email` from second table 'ContactPerson' on the same input.

This is code but not work:

```
FROM User as usr JOIN ContactPerson ctp on usr.name = :username 
AND usr.pass = :password OR ctp.email = :username
```

How can I do this?

I need login to my app with parameter name from User table or email from ContactPerson table.

Comment: What does "not work" mean? What happens?

Comment: Query doesn't work, it's popup-info 'username or password is wrong.'

Comment: User should login to app with username and password from User table OR email and password from ContactPerson table on the same Form.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to re-write your query in this way:

But I suppose you have in ContactPerson class a referral to User class (as many-to-one or a simple foreign key property)

```
FROM User as usr 
WHERE usr.pass = :password
AND (usr.name = :username 
    OR EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 FROM ContactPerson ctp WHERE ctp.email = :username
       AND ctp.user = usr)
)
```